return the longest even-length word in the sentence
consider the following data
string <- data.frame(string=c('R is a popular programming language', 'python is good'))

                               string
1 R is a popular programming language
2                      python is good

expected string2 output 

                               string  string2
1 R is a popular programming language  language
2                      python is good  python

I tried the following approach with no expected result
string <- data.frame(string=c('R is a popular programming language', 'python is good')) %>% 
  mutate(string2=strsplit(string, '\\s') %>% map(., \(x) which(str_length(x)%%2 == 0)),
         word=lapply(string, \(x) lapply(string2, \(y)  word(x,start=y, sep = '\\,')))
         )

could you please help me fix this code as it is giving error

First create a function to find the longest word in a string with an even number of characters:
get_longest_even_words <- function(str_vec, ties = c("first", "all")) {
    ties <- match.arg(ties) # if tied by default return first longest match

    str_vec_split <- strsplit(str_vec, "\\s")
    lapply(str_vec_split, \(x) {
        len <- nchar(x)
        even_len <- ifelse(len %% 2 == 0, len, -1)
        longest <- x[even_len == max(even_len)]
        if (ties == "first") longest[1] else toString(longest)
    }) |>
        unlist()
}

Then apply this to your data frame:
string |>
    transform(string2 = get_longest_even_words(string))

#                                string  string2
# 1 R is a popular programming language language
# 2                      python is good   python

As you're using dplyr, you could replace transform() with mutate().
This can deal with ties as well:
x <- "this that other"
get_longest_even_words(x, ties = "first")
# [1] "this"
get_longest_even_words(x, ties = "all")
# [1] "this, that"

